# Definitive guide for Emacs learners

Tags: emacs, ide, editor

Emacs is a huge platform. There is any "good path" to make the process of learn Emacs easier?

Comment: If you just want to learn usage, go through the built in tutorial. Follow the tutorial religiously, it's really good (and quite short). If you want to learn more general workflow, see the question linked above.

Comment: Print out the Emacs manual, put it in your bathroom or beside your bed, and ban your cell phone from both places.  Start on page 1...  Yes, seriously --- lots of interesting reading there.  After you've read a little section, think about it the next time you enter Emacs, and play with what you learned a bit.